# Writing string output to csv file. Getting error when working with temporary file

Tags: python, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm iterating through an excel file that I'm pulling from S3. I want to append this data into one file. The data isn't enough to exceed lambda memory limits so I'm saving it into a variable and then converting the string into csv file that I'm looking to upload to S3. When I run a variation of this code locally it works perfectly, not sure what's going wrong when I'm converting it to AWS.

```
import csv
import boto3
import urllib3
import tempfile

s3 = boto3.client('s3')
bucket = os.environ['S3_BUCKET']
http = urllib3.PoolManager()

def lambda_handler(event, context):
 file = readS3('example.xlsx') # load file with Boto3
 latest_scan = openpyxl.load_workbook(io.BytesIO(file), data_only=True)
 sh = latest_scan.active


 a = []
 for row in sh['A']:
    r5 = http.request(
        'GET',
        'https://example.com/api/' + str(row.value),
        headers={
            'Accept': 'text/csv'
        }
    )
    a.append(r5.data.decode('utf-8'))
 s = ''.join(a)
 temp = tempfile.TemporaryFile(mode='w+', suffix='.csv')
 with open(temp, 'w', encoding="utf-8") as f:
    for line in s:
        f.write(line)
 temp.seek(0)
 s3.put_object(temp, Bucket = bucket, Key = 'test.csv')
 temp.close()
```

I'm getting:

```
 "errorMessage": "expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not _io.TextIOWrapper",
 "errorType": "TypeError",
  "stackTrace": [
     "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line in lambda_handler\n    with open(temp, 
       'w', encoding=\"utf-8\") as f:\n"
  ]
```

Comment: You don't need to call `open()`. `tempfile.TemporaryFile()` returns an open file object, not a filename.

Answer (score 0):

`tempfile.TemporaryFile()` opens the file, it doesn't return a filename. So just assign that to `f`.

```
with tempfile.TemporaryFile(mode='w+', suffix='.csv', encoding="utf-8") as f:
```

Comment: Implemented the change which removed the initial error. Having trouble uploading the temporary file to S3 though. Is there a recommended solution? I've tried many variations and keep running into different errors.

Comment: Make sure you do the upload inside the `with` block, so the file isn't deleted. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69730782/tempfile-not-found-when-finishing-function#comment123256532_69730782