# Tempfile not found when finishing function

Tags: python, flask, backend, python-3.7, temporary-files

I am trying to create a tempfile, write to it, then download it from my flask application.. however, i am receiving a FileNotFoundError when finishing the function. Here is my code & the error received. Thanks in advance.

```
    with tempfile.TemporaryFile (mode='w', newline="", dir=".", suffix='.csv') as csvfilenew:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfilenew, delimiter= ';')
        myClick()
        return send_file(str(csvfilenew.name), as_attachment=True, attachment_filename='cleanfile.csv')
```

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Desktop/bulk_final/10'
```

Comment: Temporary files are automatically deleted when you leave the `with` block.

Comment: That's what makes it "temporary"

Comment: What exactly do you think `tempfile` means? How long do you think it should last? When you use the `with` statement for a temporary file, what do you expect that to imply about how long the file lasts?

Comment: sure, thats why i tried using send_file while within the with block. i like the tempfile because it deletes itself. i don’t want my PA app flooded with csv’s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TemporaryFile` does not return a valid filedescriptor when asked for the name attribute. You can use `NamedTemporaryFile` to ask for the name.

```
from flask import send_file
import tempfile
import csv

@app.route('/download')
def download():
    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(mode='w', newline='', dir='.', suffix='.csv') as csvfilenew:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfilenew, delimiter= ';')
        writer.writerow(['Spam', 'Lovely Spam', 'Wonderful Spam'])
        csvfilenew.flush()
        csvfilenew.seek(0)
        return send_file(csvfilenew.name,
            as_attachment=True,
            attachment_filename='cleanfile.csv'
        )
```

Another simple workaround for small amounts of data is as follows:

```
from flask import send_file
import csv
import io

@app.route('/download')
def download():
    with io.StringIO() as doc:
        writer = csv.writer(doc, delimiter= ';')
        writer.writerow(['Spam', 'Lovely Spam', 'Wonderful Spam'])
        doc.seek(0)
        return send_file(io.BytesIO(doc.read().encode('utf8')),
            as_attachment=True,
            attachment_filename='cleanfile.csv'
        )
```

Comment: Thank you ! i am at work right now & will test these out with my application when i get home !

Comment: I went with the io.StringIO route, it works ! Thanks again !